# RegEx - How to Add Anything After Selected Characters

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

I am trying to add `rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"` to all the links in HTML.

Here's the example HTML code:

```
<li><a href="https://somewebsite.com/">Some website</a></li>
<li><a href="https://awesomewebsite.net/">Awesome Website</a></li>
<li><a href="https://coolwebsite.org/">Cool Website</a></li>

<p>Also <a href="https://badsite.com/">check this website</a></p>!
```

I know nothing about RegEx but after reading some resources I have written

`href([^>]*)`

Which selects all the links but I'm not sure how would I add **rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"** in Notepad++ after what I've selected :)

I am trying to add **rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"** to all the links with RegEx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a single HTML file open you'd go through following steps. ***Be careful*** with these options and create a backup beforehand.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(href([^>]*))` or shortened and better `(href[^>]*)`
- Replace with: `$1 target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (**at your own risk!**)

This is resulting in:

[image]

For multiple HTML files, you may want to try **Find in Files** for your needs (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: The inner brackets in the RegEx seem unnecessary. I think that `(href[^>]*)` would suffice.